# openssl CSR generation gives Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST

Tags: openssl

I am trying to generate a CSR.  I understand that this command will generate both a private key and a CSR at the same time:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -nodes -keyout our.key -out our.csr
```

However, our.csr seems to be invalid.

```
openssl req -text -in our.csr -noout -verify
```

Gives:

```
unable to load X509 request 
4302814700:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:684:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST
```

Comment: The `-x509` option tells OpenSSL to output an X509 structure instead of a CSR, so just don't use that option if a CSR is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the x509 parameter this turns an CSR into an Selfsigned Certificate.
So your command is
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout our.key -out our.csr

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is in fact your error, but just for reference, if you do want to check the validity of a CSR, this command will process a CSR and display it for you. If the CSR is somehow invalid, this method will tell you that as well.

```
openssl req -noout -text -in server.csr
```